# upgrade mongo 2.0.0 to 3.0.0 directly

Tags: mongodb, upgrade

I have a production mongoDB 2.0 server running on a single machine. I need to upgrade it to the latest version. Would it be possible to just restore the dump from old server into the new server? Or would I have to do it one upgrade at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in the general case, absolutely not. Best practice is to upgrade through each major version, following the upgrade instructions in each set of [release notes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/). You can do this without downtime if you are running a replica set, at least from 2.4 -> 3.0 (I'm not as familiar with 2.0 and 2.2 since they are ancient).

Comment: Can I dump from the old database and import it to a new/different server running mongo 3.0.0?